# Associate file extension to application running in XP MODE

Tags: windows-7

I'm running a legacy application in XP mode under Win7 Professional.
The application installs, runs and publishes fine (appears in win7 start menu by itself after install).

However, when I want to associate a file extension from Win7 so that it opens automatically in that application, I don't have it on the list of available applications, and i found no way to add it there.

Anyone knows how it can be done?

I've read about associating file extensions with remote apps on TS2008, but there it's done by setting the associations in the MSI that is built on the server and used to install the app on the client. Here I have no such tools.

Help would be appreciated!

Vadim R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` commands that you can run at the CMD.EXE prompt. Here is an example from `HELP FTYPE`:

```
ASSOC .pl=PerlScript
FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*
```

I don't know if this will work with the XP mode in Windows 7, though.

Comment: Surprisingly, it works :)
It didn't work at first and I was a little confused, but it turns out the stupid application i was trying to run has two executables. One runs the main UI (and it's the one published as the XPMODE app and another .exe that is used to run the report files, which is not published. As soon as i published the second .exe and associated it with the extensions via the commands you posted, it worked.

Thanks!